# How does Jmeter Module Controller behave with consecutive user

Tags: jmeter

Jmeter - 3.0

I created Thread group -> module controller -> simple Controller -> 3 http request. When I run consecutive users(ramp up 0) will not the module controller be executed as single entity ?. Now I see all 3http request are independent(resulting in variables overwritten).

3 request are a single flow like, login -> checkout -> update some value -> logout. I want the entire flow executed  as single entity.

If I set rampup of 1 sec, I see flow completed for user but it doesnt work for rampup 0.

Any help/suggestion on this.

Thanks,
Jaya

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of performance testing is representing real users as close as it is possible. Real users are not able to do aforementioned 4 steps in 1 second, it will take at least a minute, and you should be keeping that in mind while designing your load test.

---

In regards to question itself:

1. I believe you should be using [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) instead of the Module Controller, in that case the whole flow will be considered as a single action in the reports.
2. If you want all these actions to happen in nearly the same time, you should be looking into [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)